# Uber Eats deep links?

Tags: uber-api

I know one can deep link into an uber eats restaurant using the following scheme:

`ubereats://store/browse?client_id=eats&storeUUID={STORE_UUID}`

But what about categories? Or certain types of stores 'near me'? Does Uber Eats have any other deep links besides individual stores/restaurants?

Comment: Does this work for android? I can get it to work in iOS but not chrome on android.

Answer (score 0):

Check out they're API, they have an API for list of stores

https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v1/get-eats-stores#authorization

The location is based on the authorization token you provide

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token#step-4-use-bearer-token